# Make Tool Bar Transparant in Frgament

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

I want to make Toolbar as transparent in fragment,

I have attached Image here,Here I cant able to see full image,

Can I get help from some one to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: hii, why don't you put image below toolbar? what you exactly want to do here?

Comment: can u slow some code pls?

Comment: I wanna show Toolbar as transparent.Image view has to start in tool bar

Answer (score 0):

add new style

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

set into toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```